# Is it good to insert 2 table at a time by using single stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables `Account` and `Image` and I want to insert this two tables at a time when users creates his account. Is that below stored procedure good to insert data into 2 tables, or is there any other, better way to do it?

```
Create procedure spAccountImageInsert
     (@AccID int, 
      @AccName varchar(50), 
      @Email money, 
      @ImageID int, 
      @ImageFile image)
as 
begin
    Insert into Account(AccID, AccName, Email) 
    values(@AccID, @AccName, @Email)

    Insert into Image(AccID, ImageID, ImageFile) 
    values(@AccID, @ImageID, @ImageFile)
end
```

Comment: what is byte[] in your parameter?!

Comment: @FLICKER : Sorry that not byte[] ---- image datatype

Comment: You should look at using varbinary(max) instead of image. The image datatype has been deprecated for more than a decade now.

Comment: @SeanLange : ok i do..

Comment: You should also wrap them in a transaction so that if one fails they both fail.

Comment: @BenJ.Boyle : can you provide me code

Comment: At its most basic level, place BEGIN TRANSACTION before your insert statements, and COMMIT TRANSACTION afterwards.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx or a more detailed explanation.

Comment: As @BenJ.Boyle said you should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine but always remember this could eventually grow.  If other developers touch your code this could get ugly.

What you can do is create two stored procedures one to insert an account and one to insert an image.  This at least gives you some sort of separation between your entities (this allows you to reuse names and avoids various conflicts, not to mention other things you may want to do in your sproc).  Once you insert the account you can call the stored procedure to insert an image, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertAccount
@AccountID int
AS BEGIN
--first insert into an account
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
--then insert into an image
EXEC dbo.InsertImage
END
```

Or even better a stored procedure that just executes each one:

```
EXEC dbo.InsertAccount
EXEC dbo.InsertImage
```

And don't forget about triggers...that could be a possible solution as well.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to SQL Server how to pass values to InsertImage StoredProcedure and for why i should i call triggers can you give info...

Comment: @Sri - For parameters like so `EXEC dbo.InsertImage @ImageName, @Param2, @Param3...`etc.

Comment: you said don't forget about trigger what does means

Comment: @Sri - Please do some searches on what a trigger is and how to use it.  I can only help so much.  A trigger may help you in this case but you need to determine that, just read about "Sql Server Triggers" and what they are used for.